# product of sum of positive definite matrices and the sum of inverse of them

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a set of N positive definite matrix $A_i>0$ $i=1,\cdots,N$.
Is the following true

$\frac{1}{N^2}(\sum_{i=1}^N A_i)(\sum_{i=1}^NA_i^{-1})\geq I$

If it is not true, is there any relationship between product of these two sums.

Edit: inequality is in this sense

$x^T\Big(\frac{1}{N^2}(\sum_{i=1}^N A_i)(\sum_{i=1}^NA_i^{-1})\Big)x\geq x^Tx$

$x$ is any real vector with comparable dimension to $A_i$'s

Comment: In the case $N=2$ it boils down to establish $AB^{-1}+BA^{-1}\ge 2I$ for $A,B$ - positive definite matrices. I suggest to take two such $2\times 2$ matrices at random and see what it gives.

Comment: In "Introdution to matrix analysis" by Richard Bellman, Exercise 17 from Chapter 8 (in Russian version) claims: if $X$ is positively definite then $X+X^{-1}\ge 2I$.

Comment: It seems that if we expand the left hand side of the ineqality and collect the members $A_iA_j^{-1}+A_jA_i^{-1}$ then the general inequality will be implied from the case for $N=2$.

Comment: The problem is $A_iA_j^{-1}$ is not necessarily positive definite.

Comment: The problem statement as it stands is certainly false, because the expression on the LHS is not necessarily Hermitian and hence we cannot speak of positive definite ordering in the first place. Perhaps you should amend your question.

Comment: @AlexRavsky No. E.g. consider $A=\pmatrix{4&2\\ 2&5}$ and $B=\pmatrix{4&4\\ 4&5}$. Then $\frac1{2^2}(A+B)(A^{-1}+B^{-1})=\frac1{32}\pmatrix{46&-12\\ -15&46}$, which is not even symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the above is not true. An example for $N = 3$:

$$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 86 & -18 & -6 \\
 -18 & 24 & 22 \\
 -6 & 22 & 97
\end{bmatrix}, \quad A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
 62 & -20 & 51 \\
 -20 & 19 & -1 \\
 51 & -1 & 69
\end{bmatrix}, \quad A_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
 102 & -24 & 0 \\
 -24 & 77 & -93 \\
 0 & -93 & 123
\end{bmatrix}.$$

The top left elements are positive, while the top left minors of order $2$, denoted $M_2(A_)$, are as follows:
$$M_2(A_1) = 1740 > 0, \quad M_2(A_2) = 778 > 0, \quad M_2(A_3) = 7278 > 0.$$
The determinants are:
$$\det A_1 = 131044, \quad \det A_2 = 6241, \quad \det A_3 = 12996,$$
which are all positive, so these matrices are all positive definite.

However, for $x = \begin{bmatrix} -5 & 4 & -1 \end{bmatrix}^T$, we get
$$x^T \left( \left( \sum_{i=1}^N A_i \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^NA_i^{-1} \right) - N^2{\rm I}\right) x = -62.7755 < 0.$$

I suggest you check my calculations, although I've also checked it myself.